# Multiple payments with a single autorisation (/3D secure) using stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, 3d-secure

The use case is the following: a user gets billed by the minute, therefore the total amount `amount` is not known in advance.

This is similar to what you experience at the gaz station.

Our current solution is the same as the gaz station, we hold a fixed amount (`MAX_AMOUNT`) that is greater to the maximum total amount possible bill. At the end, we capture only what has been consumed (the rest should be released `MAX_AMOUNT - amount`).

The problem of the current solution is the value of `MAX_AMOUNT` (its a bit expensive for some customers).

We though maybe we could make several smaller holds, but that would imply several 3D secure. Is there any solution that would not involve a large initial hold?

### Side note

We are using the python API (`import stripe.api_resources as api`) and:

- register the user's card using `api.checkout.Session.create`;
- then, hold `MAX_AMOUT` using `api.PaymentIntent.create`;
- and finally capture `amount` using `api.PaymentIntent.capture`.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking this up into multiple payments does not really make it less expensive, as the customer still has the total held on their cards, the same as one large hold. You would be increasing your paid Stripe fees with multiple payments, too.

Really what you're doing is already optimal with a pre-auth amount then capture for the real amount. You need to optimize the amount you hold initially based on your knowledge of the customer and predicted payment.

For customers that end up exceeding that amount, you can do an additional auth when needed to cover that.

Note that you can skip your middle step by using checkout `payment` mode with manual capture: `payment_intent_data[capture_method]=manual` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-capture_method))

And for the later payments you should ensure you set `setup_future_usage`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-setup_future_usage

Comment: I've heard rumors of people managing to split a single hold into several smaller holds over time wihout requiring multiple autorisations (3D secures). After you consumed X euros, X more euros are hold, etc. This allows to relieve the pain of a single large hold amount for customers who actually consume smaller amounts of time). Does setting `setup_future_usage= off_session` allows to capture a second time without having a second 3D secure? The documentations says "Setups for off-session payments are more likely to incur additional friction" any idea what that means?